# Is there any way to dispute moderator flags such as "duplicate"?

Tags: support

Recently I posted a question that asked a slightly similar (but not anywhere near exactly the same as) question which had already been posted by another user. Shortly thereafter, it was closed as a "Duplicate" by a moderator, and I was not given a chance to edit/change it or what-not before the question simply disappeared from my profile.

Is there any way to dispute these flags when they come up? Should I contact the site admins or the flagging mod directly?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Also, please forgive my ignorance if this has already been addressed. I signed up today and I've been going through the FAQs and what-not but I haven't come across anything that talks about this.

Edit II: Per Anna's request, here is the link to the question to which I'm referring: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76484/i-feel-like-i-am-capable-of-learning-how-to-code-but-i-lose-motivation-because-i

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Programmers!

Making a meta post is exactly the right way to dispute something like that. Please include the link to the question that you think was wrongly closed.

Comment: Hi, Anna. Thank you very much for the reply. Here is the link to the question in... Question.. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/76484/i-feel-like-i-am-capable-of-learning-how-to-code-but-i-lose-motivation-because-i